# Best editor like Gutenberg in React JS

Tags: reactjs, editor, gutenberg-blocks

I would like to use the best editor which custommizable in React Js. Which is up-to-date, full of technology and a lot of features it should have.

I have explored the gutenberg editor but can't find its latest editor to use in React, older one is compatible with React.
Need best editor suggestions for `ReactJS`

Comment: I'm afraid your question is off-topic here.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ReactJS you can also use [EditorJS.io](https://editorjs.io/). Its customizable and also compatible with ReactJS. Secondly, if you want to use Gutenberg as your editor you can check this repo: [Block-Editor](https://github.com/Automattic/isolated-block-editor).

Next there are Quill Editors libraries in ReactJs which are also very good to utilize in your app.

Comment: Please don't respond to off-topic questions (this one being a recommendation request). Also, link-only answers are not valid answers.